# Minimum system requirements

Tags: discussion, merge

Firstly, should these two be merged/duped/linked/somethinged:

- [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) (I think this is the best out of em)
- [What are the system requirements for each flavour of Ubuntu Desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333795/what-are-the-system-requirements-for-each-flavour-of-ubuntu-desktop)

Also, should these now include the minimum specs needed for [Ubuntu Snappy Core](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/) (i've looked and can't find them, so it would be helpful (also if it is soo minimal it may work for [this](https://askubuntu.com/q/617871/178596))) - I know there is [a version for the Raspberry Pi 2](https://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/snappy/) so it is fairly low-specced.

EDIT: for the latter issue, I half found and answer so did [What are the minimum system requirements for Ubuntu Snappy Core?](https://askubuntu.com/q/617904/178596)

Comment: We don't dupe questions because the answers are similar (usually), we dupe them because the questions are the same. Those two are not the same question and they aren't equal to each other. Thanks for helping to maintain them though!